# Angular flicker in a javafx webview

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javafx, webview, javafx-webengine

I'm building an angular app running inside a javafx webview, and when I bind two elements' ng-show (or ng-class) to a single scope variable they are, for a moment, both visible.

I have tried the following styles:

```
    <span class="actual-text" ng-class="{placeholder-text:mainCtrl.insertedText.length > 0}">
    {{mainModels.insertedText||'a place holder text'}}
    </span>
```

and

```
    <span class="actual-text" ng-show="mainCtrl.insertedText.length > 0">{{mainModels.insertedText }}</span>
    <span class="placeholder-text" ng-show="mainCtrl.insertedText.length == 0">{{mainModels.placeholder}}</span>
```

with the same results. binding them to different scope vars (and manually setting the order of appearance for those) will be my last resort but seems like a very non-angular solution to me. Did anyone else notice such a problem? Is it something fundamentally wrong with my angular code?

**EDIT**
the code works on a regular browser.
the problem disappears when I Don't inject the ng-material module to my app...

Comment: I suppose the angular app works in a normal browser like Chrome, which uses the same base for rendering (WebKit)? What Java version are you using?

Comment: You are correct in supposing that :) also, the problem disappears when I Don't inject the ng-material module to my app...